# Trouble installing Rails

Tags: rvm

Ok, imploded my rvm today (for reasons I cannot remember now, and pretty much cursing myself for it) ...

Have installed it back.

Trying to install rails ...

This is what I keep getting:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
```

No idea what it means ...

How do I fix this?

Side Note: 
Now I remember why I imploded my rvm. It was to install readline package. I wanted to have rails console, and thought that was the way to go ...

Comment: What is your `rvm -v`?

Comment: @alestanis version is rvm 1.18.18

Comment: @alestanis version is 1.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a

```
gem update --system
```

to update your RubyGems. It should put you in version 2.0.

Comment: This is what I got: Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.0.2
Updating RubyGems to 2.0.2
Installing RubyGems 2.0.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem

Comment: @oyvey Your `ruby -v`? ;) Are you using 1.8??

Comment: @oyvey try it with `sudo` in front: `sudo gem update --system`

Comment: ugh, didn't read that thoroughly as I should have. No, obviously not. =) Will update it. By the way, rails finally got installed. Thank you!

Comment: @oyvey Great! I know installs can be a pain

Comment: just one more question ... do i need readline package for rails console, or did i understand that wrongly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25811/discussion-between-alestanis-and-oy-vey)